# MySQL - Join table on column A unless column A = x then join on column b instead

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Is it possible to Join a table on a different column if the first column is equal to a specific value.

See below:

tableA

```
  .----+-----------------.
  | ID | Name            |
  +----+-----------------+
  |  1 | Name goes here1 |
  |  2 | Name goes here2 |
  |  3 | Name goes here3 |
  |  4 | Name goes here4 |
  .----+-----------------+
```

tableB

```
  .----+-----------------+-----------------.
  | ID | id1             | id2             |
  +----+-----------------+-----------------+
  |  1 | ID goes here    | ID goes here    |
  |  2 | ID goes here    | ID goes here    |
  |  3 | ID goes here    | ID goes here    |
  |  4 | ID goes here    | ID goes here    |
  .----+-----------------+-----------------.
```

So for example, I would like to join tableA ON tableA.ID = tableB.id1 UNLESS tableB.id1 = x THEN JOIN ON tableB.id2

Comment: Can you please add the desired output also in question? It will be easy to help you then.

Comment: Can x be null??

Comment: `ON (tableA.ID = tableB.id1 AND tableB.id1 <> x) OR (tableA.ID = tableB.id2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can express this as basic logic in the `on` clause:

```
on (a.id = b.id1 and b.id1 <> x) or
   (a.id = b.id2 and b.id1 = x)
```

The logic is slightly more complicated if `x` can be `NULL`, but you can definitely use the same idea.  If the idea is to test for `NULL`, then an easier way to express the query is:

```
on a.id = coalesce(b.id1, b.id2)
```

Comment: What about if x is null?

Comment: It doesnt matter if `x`is null... it will only affect the operator... the logic is the same...

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked a treat :-D